# Uploading large files using Classic ASP and IIS7.5

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have an upload script (based on the upload.asp file published by a Jacob "Beezle" Gilley). This works very well for me in a Classic ASP application and as long as I have the Server.ScriptTimeout set to a suitable value AND the 'Maximum allowed content length' setting configured in IIS7.5.

From my browsers (Firefox, Chrome or even IE) I can happily upload jpg images of 35Mb...

But, my customer uses IE9 and gets an error when she uploads big (12Mb images) - smaller images are ok. The error she's seeing is a basic "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" - it's not a 404 or even a 500 error.

Unfortunately, her IT department won't allow any other browsers. So, I've setup a virtual Windows 7 PC with IE9, but cannot recreate the issue.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable upload of large files in classic ASP on IIS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989334/how-do-i-enable-upload-of-large-files-in-classic-asp-on-iis-7)

Comment: First you need her to turn off `Show Friendly HTTP Errors` in the Advanced tab in `Internet Options`, that way you will see the original error.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 7.5 under web site:

```
- Under ASP:
    -- under limits change max req entity and buffering limit to [big number]
- under Management (at bottom) go into "Configuration Editor".
    -- In the dropdown go to System.web --> http runtime and change maxRequestLength to [big number]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written an extensive answer on this topic here [How do I enable upload of large files in classic ASP on IIS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22386054/692942)

Should contain all the information you need to get large uploads working for classic asp on IIS 7+.

Comment: Sorry posted my answer based off the question title then read the full question.

Comment: @JezB Have you tried my other suggestion about the `Show Friendly Error Messages` that is on by default in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Thanks Lankymart - there was no error - IE reported communication lost. We've just discovered that it was the company network that was causing the problem. I'm still waiting to hear exactly what they've changed, but I'll post it on here when I know...