# File uploading in classic asp using clsupload.asp

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

I am uploading files from classic asp using clsupload.asp. The class is uploading files successfully but when file size is more that 200 kb it is throwing error.

Please help me.

Comment: I am new in classic asp. Can you please elaborate the answer. There is a folder named images where they are uploading. So, what should I put there in web.cnofig?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your version of IIS but a simple search would have found your answer pretty quickly

IIS7 -[How do I enable upload of large files in classic ASP on IIS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989334/how-do-i-enable-upload-of-large-files-in-classic-asp-on-iis-7)

IIS6 - http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/file_upload_limits.asp