# IIS web.config in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have a classic asp site hosted in IIS 7.5. Currently it allows me to upload only <200KB files. The hosting provider said that I should put that limit in web.config. I do not know how to increase the limit using web.config.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable upload of large files in classic ASP on IIS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989334/how-do-i-enable-upload-of-large-files-in-classic-asp-on-iis-7)

Comment: This has been answered before. If you want a full breakdown go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22386054/692942)

Answer (score 0):

ASP Limits properties are by default located in the server applicationHost.config, if you don't have access to it, your hosting provider must delegate ASP feature to lower levels.

Once it is done, put this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
        <asp>
            <limits maxRequestEntityAllowed="200000000" />
        </asp>
    </system.webServer>
```

Note that if the server is not delegating this feature properly, you will get an error when trying to do a request to your app.

Comment: Well we had the same exact upload file problem with our asp classic apps and this is the only thing we had to do for bigger upload sizes to work

Comment: Read that post to understand how it's relevant.

Comment: You should bear in mind that hosting providers' tech support don't always know everything and you may need to explain all this.  Unless you're using with a dedicated Windows provider you often find yourself dealing with UNIX people.

Comment: Just because the default is in `applicationHost.config` doesn't mean you can't include that section in the web applications own `web.config` to override it. Changing values in the `applicationHost.config` is overkill.