# asp limits maxRequestEntityAllowed IIS 7 is not working on single page, only works on all the website

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7, web-config

I have to increase request size limit for a specific page in a classic asp website in order to post larger amount of data.

I go in IIS > Asp > Limits Properties, and change the value in "Maximum Requesting Entity Body Limit" property.

Strangely it works fine when I change the property on all the website, but if I change it only on the specific asp page (Content View > Right click on the file > Switch to features view > IIS > ASP > Limits properties...) where I post my data it does not work.

For obvious reason I don't want to allow such big posts on all the website, but I don't find why it doesn't work on a single page.

In my applicationHost.config:

```
<location path="Default Web Site/FolderXYZ/MyPage.asp">
    <system.webServer>
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="false">
            <limits maxRequestEntityAllowed="1000000" />
        </asp>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

EDIT: I also checked for request filtering like explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989334/how-do-i-enable-upload-of-large-files-in-classic-asp-on-iis-7/22386054#22386054) but the default setting is already larger than what i need, so it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a dedicated site for that form and use its webform in an iFrame on the main site's web page.